# couchbase push error

Tags: forms, couchdb, push, couchbase

I am learning how to push a document to couchbase (couchdb) from a form and I am getting an error: "Document could not be saved: missing function"

I have tried several ways, my current attempt is here:

```
  $db = $.couch.db("testdb");

  $("form.edit-contact").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var editContact = {
      _id: $("input[name=id]").val(),
      _rev: $("input[name=rev]").val(),
      name: $("input[name=contact]").val(),
      phone: $("input[name=phone]").val(),
      email: $("input[name=email]").val()
    };
    $db.saveDoc(editContact, {
      success : function(resp) {
        alert ('saved');
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
```

Firebug is showing a breaking point:

encodeDocId  jquery.couch.js (line 17)
var parts = docID.split("/");

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try to add 'error: function(code, error, reason) { alert("Error("+code+" "+error+"): "+reason); }' to saveDoc() options? Are you using CouchApp?

Comment: what is the value of your input[name=id] field in this case (which should also be the value of docID)? Do you get any additional errors when Firebug breaks on that line?

Answer (score 0):

Hit me,

but I think your keys and values need to be surrounded by " ? 
Like this: {"id":"478d86edbbd94bbe627f3ebda30d4bf1","key":null,"value":"HTC"}

And I use

```
   jQuery.parseJSON( document )
```

right now.

Regards, Chris

Comment: In Javascript keys need not be quoted.

Comment: but in JSON they do need to be. If he's parsing "document" as JSON, then they should be quoted. If he's encoding a JS object into JSON (or just using the JS object within the JS code only), then the keys don't need to be quoted. Its an annoying, but important distinction. :)